# If then with a checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet. I am trying to do an if then statment.

If cell C8=True then I want it to perform a function. I know this is not right but wanted to give you guys example of what I am writing

```
=IF(C7=TRUE,"=REPT("l",a140)")
```

What I want to happen is when a check box is check or shows "true" I want an cell to show a status bar for my customer.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=IF(C7=TRUE,REPT("l",A140),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I tried you example changing the formula this way:

```
=IF(C7=TRUE; REPT("l";A140);"")
```

Last “” is the “else” statement, when C7 is false. This way I can make it works.

Cheers